# How to create a statement to count total of date and time

Tags: excel-formula, countif, sumifs

I have data in two separate columns like this

[image: two columns]

But how can I count how many rows are occurring within say a window of 6 AM to 10 PM and outside a window of 10:01 PM to 5:59 AM?

The first column cells are formatted as General. The second column cells are custom h:mm:ss

Fuller View

[image]

Here I have a formula to count how many times "Mon" comes up in the left column

```
=COUNTIF($D:$D,"*"&$K5&"*")
```

And this is what I have when I try to combine the two to determine how many "Mon" entries were between 06:00 AM and 10:30 PM

```
=COUNTIFS($D:$D,"*"&$K5&"*",$E:$E,SUMPRODUCT((E2:E119>=M4)*(E2:E119<N4)))
```

but I get a fat 'ol zero

Yet if I run

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E2:E119>=M4)*(E2:E119<N4))
```

I get 116 as a return for the amount of times that a cell is between 06:00 AM and 10:30 PM

So BLUF - I want to count how many times a row has "Mon" and a corresponding time between 06:00 AM and 10:30 PM then I can replicate it for the rest of the days of the week.

New update-dtd 10/11/2022

Right now I know that there are 4 instances where Tuesday had after-hours calls:
Instance one was at 5:59 AM on the 11th
Instance two was at 5:57 AM on the 11th
Instance three was at 10:39 PM on the 11th
& Instance four was at 10:36 PM on the 11th

but with the formula of =COUNTIFS($D:$D,"*"&$K7&"*",$E:$E,">="&$O$5,$E:$E,">"&$P$5)
I am only accounting for 2 of those instances - the 10:39 PM and the 10:36 PM instance (found this out by testing/removing the values in the cells to see what changed the total).
How would I capture the times that are between midnight and 05:59 AM, to include 5:59 AM?
[image]

Comment: If you formatted the second column as general are they are decimals with 0 as the int?

Comment: I could do that. Right now I can have it down to I can count how many times in the left column are say "Monday" and I can count how many of the events are between the hours of 6 AM and 10:30 PM but I can seem to figure out how to combine the two.

Comment: You do not say you want to use the day of the week in your question.  Please [edit] the post to include all criteria needed.  Otherwise you are going to get incorrect answer.

Comment: I hope that edit helps. I am trying to count how many times a row meets 2 criteria. 
1) "Mon" from the left column and in the right column 
2) a time that lies between 06:00 AM and 10:30 PM.
If a row meets both those criteria then that's an individual count to be tallied.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS($D:$D,"*"&$K5&"*",$E:$E,">="&M4,$E:$E,"<"&N4)`

Comment: @ScottCraner You are a genius my friend. Nice, elegant, short, and sweet. Just the way I like it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ScottCraner solved this with
=COUNTIFS($D:$D,"*"&$K5&"*",$E:$E,">="&M4,$E:$E,"<"&N4)